# Copy data to a new file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a new Excel file with data from a main (with VBA) Excel file.

I can only Save as and it is saving my main Excel file.

I need a copy of this file with certain cells and columns.

How the copy of the Excel file should look
[image]

I have this.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim newExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim newWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim newWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set newWorkbook = newExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Set newWorkSheet = newWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    newWorkSheet.Range("A1") = "Klients"
    newWorkSheet.Range("B1") = "Bilance 06.17"
    newWorkSheet.Range("C1") = "Bilance 07.17"
    newWorkSheet.Range("D1") = "Bilance 08.17"
    newWorkSheet.Range("E1") = "Bilance 09.17"
    newWorkSheet.Range("F1") = "Bilance 10.17"
    newWorkSheet.Range("G1") = "Kopa"
    newWorkSheet.Range("A2") = TextBox1.Text
    newWorkSheet.Range("B2") = TextBox2.Text
    newWorkSheet.Range("C2") = TextBox3.Text
    newWorkSheet.Range("D2") = TextBox4.Text
    newWorkSheet.Range("E2") = TextBox5.Text
    newWorkSheet.Range("F2") = TextBox6.Text
    newWorkSheet.Range("G2") = TextBox7.Text

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\" & newExcel
.Execute
End Sub
```

Comment: you only want to exclude the vba? but save the data? or you want to chage the content of the file as well?

Comment: Try `With newExcel.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)`. Because you need to invoke the SaveAs dialog from the "new" instance of excel you've created via `CreateObject`, rather than from the "main" instance of excel.

Comment: @DavidZemens
Where I have to put it?

Comment: Where do you think? ?

Comment: @Atreyagaurav
Yes.Soo I have in main file more that 1000 clients numers,balance and etc.
I'm need to take one client info(numbers,balance and etc.) and save it in specific place(which I'm need to choose through Save As menu.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe this:

```
With newExcel
    .Visible = True
    With .FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\" & newExcel.Workbooks(1).name
        .Show
        '.Execute
    End With
    ' If you nedd to close
    .Quit
    Thisworkbook.Activate
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance, copy the values to it and then save that instance(new). You haven't shown the code where you tried to save it. `newWorkbook.saveas` where you put the filename parameter from filedialogbox should work.
Or just do `NewWorkbook.Save` since it is a new workbook, the filename picker may apper by default.